# (Python) merge new and existing JSON with deduplication

Tags: python, json, merge

I'm querying an API with Python, This API sends JSON of the last X events and I want to keep a history of what it sent me.

So this is what the API sends, and I have the same type of elements in my flat history file (but with many more of the same objects).
The API and my final file doesn't have a key on which to setup a dictionary.

```
[{
    "Item1": "01234",
    "Item2": "Company",
    "Item3": "XXXXXXXXX",
    "Item4": "",
    "Item5": "2015-12-17T12:00:01.553",
    "Item6": "2015-12-18T12:00:00"
},
{
    "Item1": "01234",
    "Item2": "Company2",
    "Item3": "XXXXXXX",
    "Item4": null,
    "Item5": "2015-12-17T16:49:23.76",
    "Item6": "2015-12-18T11:00:00",
}]
```

How do I add up elements of the API only if they are not in the original file?
I have a skeleton of opening/closing file but have not many ideas about the processing.

```
main_file=open("History.json","r")
new_items=[]
api_data=requests.get(#here lies the api address and the header)
#here should be the deplucation/processing process
for item in api_data
    if item not in main_file 
        new_items.append(item)
main_file.close()
try:
    file_updated = open("History.json",'w')
    file_updated.write(new_items + main_file)
    file_updated.close()
    print("File updated")
except :
    print("Error writing file")
```

EDIT : I used the json to object method to do this :

```
from collections import namedtuple
Event = namedtuple('Event', 'Item1, Item2, Item3, Item4, Item5, Item6')
def parse_json_events(text):
    events = [ Event(**k) for k in json.loads(text) ]
    return events
if path.exists('Mainfile.json'):
    with open('Mainfile.json') as data_file:
        local_data = json.load(data_file)
        print(local_data.text) #debug purposes
        events_local=parse_json_events(local_data.text)
else:
    events_local=[]
events_api=parse_json_events(api_request.text)
inserted_events=0 
for e in events_api[::-1]:
    if e not in events_local:
        events_local.insert(0, e)
        inserted_events=inserted_events+1
print("inserted elements %d"  % inserted_events)
print(events_local) # this is OK, gives me a list of events
print(json.dump(events_local)) # this ... well... I want the list of object to be serialized but I get this error :
```

> TypeError: dump() missing 1 required positional argument: 'fp'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you solve this kind of problems by defining a schema with/without a third party tool (like Avro, Thrift, etc.). Basically, every record you get from the API needs to be translated to an entity in the programming language you are using.

Let's take as an example this JSON object:

```
{
    "Item1": "01234",
    "Item2": "Company",
    "Item3": "XXXXXXXXX",
    "Item4": "",
    "Item5": "2015-12-17T12:00:01.553",
    "Item6": "2015-12-18T12:00:00"
},
```

If you have a schema like

```
Company(object):
  company_number = ...
  name = ...
  # other fields
```

Then, all you need to do is to serialize and deserialize the raw data.

Ideally, you'd read the JSON response from the API and then you could simply split each json object as a schema object (with or without a tool). In pseudocode:

```
api_client = client(http://..., )
response = api_client.get("/resources")
json = response.json 
companies = parse_json_companies(json) # list of Company objects
```

At this point, it's really easy to handle the data you got from the api. You should do the same for the files you have stored on the filesystem. Load your files and deserialize the records (to Company objects). Then, it will be easy to compare the objects, as they will be like "normal" Python objects, so that you can perform comparisons, etc etc.

For example:

```
from collections import namedtuple
import json
Company = namedtuple('Company', 'Item1, Item2, Item3, Item4, Item5, Item6')
def parse_json_companies(text):
  companies = [Company(**k) for k in json.loads(text)]
  return companies

>>> companies = parse_json_companies(response.json)
>>> companies
[Company(Item1='01234', Item2='Company', Item3='XXXXXXXXX', Item4=u'', Item5='2015-12-17T12:00:01.553', Item6='2015-12-18T12:00:00'), Company(Item1='01234', Item2='Company2', Item3='XXXXXXX', Item4=None, Item5='2015-12-17T16:49:23.76', Item6='2015-12-18T11:00:00')]
```

**Update after error on .dump(obj, fp) .**

If you get the error with json.dump, refer to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.dump) please. It clearly states that **obj** and **fp** are required arguments.

> Serialize obj as a JSON formatted stream to fp (a .write()-supporting file-like object) using this conversion table.

So, you need to pass an object that supports .write (e.g., a file opened in write mode).

Comment: This seems to be what I wanted to do, though, doing myself JSON to object parsing seemed to be recreating the wheel, I thought there would be another way of doing it natively or with a python library.

Comment: Well, all you need to do is to write your json decoder. https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html

Comment: I updated the answer. I hope now you understand better how to do it.

Comment: woaw thanks, but I seem to have a problem at the 4th line with invalid syntax... you sir open "[" but never closes "]" isn't there an issue?

Comment: companies= [Company(**k) for k in json.loads(text))]
                                                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: it should be: events = [ Event(**k) for k in json.loads(text) ]

Comment: the json to object works well ! thanks !!! i'm pasting my code cleaned up for S.O. when it's ready so everyone can have it

Comment: Although it's really kind of you, AFAIK it's not required. However, you might accept an answer once you are sure it's the correct one - so that it doesn't appear anymore in the "unanswered" list of answers.

Comment: I'll try it on monday (i don't have access to the code right now but I'll do it when I'm sure thannks !

Comment: hello, it seems this is the answer I was looking for, but when I want to save the file with the new python list of objects, json.dump() doesn't work. I get     print(json.dump(events_local))
TypeError: dump() missing 1 required positional argument: 'fp'

Comment: As usual, please update your question with the new details. :) Including the code you are referring to, please.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way of solving this would be to think about your data structure. It seems like you're using the same data structure as the api at this moment.

Is there an `Id` among these item fields? If so use that field for deduplication. But for this example I'll use company name.

```
with open('history.json') as f:
    historic_data = json.load(f)
    api_data = requests.get()
    for item in api_data:
        historic_data[item['Item2']] = item
    f.write(json.dumps(historic_data))
```

Every time the name in this case already exists in the dictionary it will be overwritten. If the name isn't existing it will be added.

Comment: @kuzko, let me know if it answered your question :)

Comment: unfortunately, no, the API is not giving me any unique key to reference the object by, so it's a full object to full object comparison that I need to do, the company name repeats itself in other objects, like all the other fields...